# Getting 404 from the Twilio Voice Insights API when fetching summaries and metrics

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-python

I am trying to get the the summary for call records from the rest API and I am getting
404 every time on every single calls SIDs. I am using latest version of twilio-python helper library to send requests.

```py
insights_response = client.insights.v1.calls.get(CALL_SID).summary.get().fetch()
```

I tried the same thing with CURL and got the same results.

```sh
curl -X GET https://insights.twilio.com/v1/Voice/CAxxxxx/Summary \
-u "sid:auth token"
```

We have insights enabled on console as well and can see those records on console. I need to access them via API.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have advanced voice insights enabled?

Advanced Voice Insights
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/insights/advanced-features

Comment: Hi, yes. Advanced Insights are enabled in the settings. I am able to get metrics resource . Just not the summary resource.

Comment: The API doesn't return data for calls older than 30 days, could that be the issue?

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue, I can now get records for new calls.